# プロトコルを準拠しているクラスか調べる方法

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcodeやドキュメントでうまく調べる方法についてご質問です。

プロトコルを準拠しているクラスか調べる方法はありますでしょうか？

例えば、`Color構造体`が`ShapeStyleプロトコル`に準拠しておりますが、`Developer Documation`を開いて右側にある`Relationships`をクリックしても`ShapeStyle`が見つかりませんでした。

おそらく基底クラスで準拠していると思います。コードエディタから`Jump to Definition`して追っていくしか方法はないのでしょうか？

基底クラスを含めて簡単に調べることを出来ると助かります。

Comment: ***おそらく基底クラスで準拠していると思います*** (そもそも構造体やプロトコルに「基底クラス」と言う言い方は使いませんが、意味は通じるのでそこは良いとして)誤りです。`Color`がドキュメントで明示的に適合しているとされるプロトコルは、`CustomStringConvertible, 
Hashable, 
View`の3つだけですが、このうち継承関係があるのは`Hashable`のみ(`Equatable`を継承)です。`Color`が`ShapeStyle`に適合することを示せていないのは、 ***ドキュメントバグ*** だと考えられます。「継承により適合しているプロトコルも簡単に調べられるようにしてほしい」といった要望も含め、Appleにドキュメントバグの報告を送られると良いでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

基底クラスと書く時にどのように書いたらいいか迷って書きました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。やはりドキュメントに記載がないだけの様子なんですね。要望を報告してみたいと思います。ご回答ありがとうございました。